# the_permalink_rss filter doesn't work

Tags: wordpress, rss, feed

the RSS feed of annuncistar.it isn't valid because the "&" char is not allowed in RSS feeds.
In order to solve that issue I've added a WordPress filter in my functions.php file.

```
function mp_permalink($permalink) {
$url = str_replace("&", "&amp;", $permalink);
return $url;
}

add_filter('the_permalink_rss', 'mp_permalink');
```

Unfortunately this function doesn't work. What could the reason be?

Comment: The feed looks like it's picking up the ampersands from Google Analytics variables that are being added to the normal feed URL. Do you know what's doing that? Do you have some feed/Google analytics plugin running?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately someone before me has installed a lot of plugins and I don't know precisely which of them is the cause of this issue.
Anyway I will investigate and I will report which plugin causes this issue.

Comment: I've deactivated a plugin for Google Analytica and now everything works fine.

Thanks

Comment: Glad you've fixed it. I've added a full answer with more details of what's going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your feed URL seems to have Google Analytics tracking variables (utm_source, etc.) appended to it. Normally, a WordPress feed URL looks as simple as (to take mine as an example):

```
http://gothick.org.uk/feed
```

However, with Analytics tracking variables, it looks something like this:

```
http://gothick.org.uk/?utm_source=source&utm_medium=medium&utm_term=term&utm_content=content&utm_campaign=campaign
```

So, I'm guessing that you have a plugin installed that is altering your feed URL to add these variables. Unfortunately, when it's being embedded in your RSS feed as the feed source, the ampersands in the URL aren't being escaped -- I'd guess this is a bug in the plugin.

I'd guess your filter isn't being run *after* the plugin changes the original feed. Whether that's because it's being run earlier in the filter chain or because the analytics plugin is targeting the feed URL at a different level, I'm not sure.

Either way, the solution will be to disable the analytics plugin, or at least the bit that alters the feed URL, or update it to a version that escapes the URL properly for use in the RSS feed XML.